# C# Changing original form size?

Tags: c#, forms, size

I'm trying to change the original form size.

I want to show to user only just checkedListBox1 at first.

[image]

And when user clicks some kind of a button, they see all four of the boxes.

[image]

But because it is bind to the first form size(lets say width, height(100,100)), I can't get the anchor right when user are trying to shrink or enlarge the form.

For example, when I make 25 by 25 just to show checkedListBox1

Because it is stick to 100 by 100 originally the shrink or enlarging doesn't work properly.

Is there anyway to make the checkedListBoxes size stay the same as it was but the form pretends to be set like it was originally 25 by 25 (the original size is 100 by 100)?

Comment: Did you try setting `this.Size` ?

Comment: yes but when i do that, all the check boxes shrink as the form shrinks. Step 1, I got rid of anchors for the check boxes. Step 2, I down sized the form size with this.Size. Step 3, I put the anchors back again to check boxes. Still... doesn't work properly. I gotta do it again but I asked question, if i could get any hints. Thank you!

Comment: Then anchor them all `Left,Top` rather than what i'm guessing is `Left,Top.Right,Bottom`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it's seems like a question about layout.

In winforms you have `AutoSize` property and `TableLayoutPanel`/`FlowLayoutPanel` to create dynamic layouts easily.

---

### [image]

Guide:

- add `TableLayoutPanel` (2 columns, 2 rows, set each to `Auto` after adding content), set it dock;
- add content (`CheckedListBox`es), set `Visibility = False` to initially hidden ones;
- set `AutoSize = True` and `AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink` to form and `TableLayoutPanel`;
- in checkbox `CheckedChanged` event change `Visibility` and the rest happens automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Add your control within the panel and dock/anchor the panel and then try to resize.it works fine.